# Как переложить данные из мапы в двумерный массив?

Tags: java, массивы

Хочу прочитать данные из таблицы mysql и отобразить их в виде таблицы при помощи JTable. Есть ли предложения, как это можно грамотно реализовать?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Понятия не имею, как именно вы извлекаете данные из БД и какая страктура таблиц в вашей БД, а также не вижу каких-либо проблем с тем, чтобы отобразить двумерный массив в JTable, поэтому отвечу синтетическим примером на вопрос из заголовка:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class MapTo2DArray {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> input = new HashMap<>();
        //Забиваем Map данными
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
            .forEach(i -> input.put(String.format("Key%d", i), String.format("Value %d", i)));

        //Конвертируем Map в двумерный массив
        String[][] output = input.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new String[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()})
            .toArray(String[][]::new);

        //Выводим результат
        for(String[] row : output) {
            System.out.format("%s = %s\n", row[0], row[1]);
        }
    }
}
```